# Reducing Android Alternative Drawable Resources

Tags: android, drawable, android-resources

I have images that need to scale to the screen's size. The images will also have text in it that needs to be translated to a second language. So there will be two versions of each image to start, one for each language.

Google recommends having an image resource per density. So I'd take my two images and multiply them by four: xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, and ldpi. But then Google say to have different image resource for different screen sizes. This multiplies my images by four again: xlarge, large, normal, and small. I don't want to create 32 copies of every image!

I'm wondering if there is anything wrong with making the images for xlarge screens and xhdpi densities only. IE – Best quality. Let Android scale down the images for lower densities per its standards for dp units. And when I draw on smaller screens, I could use the Canvas class to scale down further. I could cache the resulting scaled Bitmap object for use every time it needs to redraw the bitmap to avoid expensive scaling computations running over and over.

Is there any drawback to doing this? Or is there a better way to avoid making so many copies of the same image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a performance penalty in downscaling large images on smaller (low-end) devices.  Whether this will be noticeable depends on the number of images you have to show.
The same holds, mutatis mutandis, for memory.

Comment: Thanks, good feedback. One point for clarification: I was hoping that by caching the downscaled bitmap then it should garbage collect the original larger image. I don't think this one-time GC event will be impactful enough to make a diffence for this particular app. But do you know if the downscaled cached Bitmap instance will be the same memory footprint or will it be larger than if it were instantiated using Google's alternate resource method? (Assume both methods result in bitmaps of the same physical dimensions.) If larger then that might be a problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure how you intend to downscale so it's difficult to give a final answer (provided that I know it :-) ). You could do the following (indirect) test though: after loading a Bitmap from the resources, I assume that isMutable() will return false.  I guess that after scaling, the resulting bitmap will have isMutable()=true indicating, indirectly, that it is a copy and hence  is likely to have its own memory.

Answer (score 0):

I create bitmaps only for the highest xhdpi pixel density, and then test on other screen types.

If a bitmap looks bad on some lower-density screen, I remake it specifically for that density. And this happens quite rarely...

Also, making special bitmaps for different screen sizes (small/xlarge) is not needed - just make your ImageView-s smaller/larger - image scaling is not a slow operation, so in most cases you don't need to worry about it either (unless your bitmaps cover the whole screen).